# REST API URL naming convention

Tags: api, rest, microservices

I would like to check if an order is active with retrieving the order details. I have an enpoint designed similar to what is listed below

```
/order/{order-id}
```

However I was to check if the order is active without retreiving the details of the order. Which of the below is a better approach to do this or are there any other alernatives?

```
/order/{order-id}/is-active
```

or

```
/order/is-active/{order-id}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django Rest Framework, a widely used REST API framework, uses the second form `/order/{order-id}/is-active`.

See [Routing for extra actions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions) and [Reversing action URLs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#reversing-action-urls) for examples of this in their documentation.